# Differentiation optimisation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization

I have a question stating that an insulation strip is to be sealed completely around three edges of a rectangular solar panel. The length of this strip is 200cm.

It is asking what dimension of the panel would create the biggest area, and what this area is.

I just wanted to check that I have done it right.

My first step was to draw a box and label the vertical sides y, and the horizontals x.

I then draw the insulation strip going up the two y sides and across one horizontal. I figured the horizontal side x would then be equal to $x=200-2y$.

I can then sub this back into the normal rectangle area equation $A=x*y$ which makes the equation $$A=(200-2y)*y$$

I then wanted to find the y value when A was at a maximum so I differentiated then made the rate of change =0 to find the extrema points.

$\frac{d}{dy}A = \frac{d}{dy}200y - \frac{d}{dy}2y^2$

$=200-4y$

Make rate of change =0 to find extremas

$200-4y=0$

$y=\frac{200}{4}$
$=50$

Being only 1 point I thought this would be the only solution and therefore the maximum area of the panel would occur when $y=50cm$ (and $x=100$)

Subbing back into equation

$A_{max}=50(200-2(50))$

$=5000cm^2$

Does this seem correct/is there anything I can do to improve on the working out for exams etc? Thanks

Comment: Everything you did is correct.  If you want to double check that this is indeed a maximizing value, note that $A^{\prime\prime}(y)=-4<0$ for all $y$; thus, by the second derivative test, the value you found ($y=50$) is a maximum for $A(y)$.

Comment: Alternately note $A = 200y-2y^2 = 5000-2(y-50)^2$ by completing the square.

Answer (score 1):

That is perfect. Great job! You know your stuff.

Comment: Ummm. The sum of three sides is given, not the perimeter. The final result is fine, though your approach would need tweaking.